# How to handle this error in C# "Required Member must be set in object initiialzer or attribute constructor"

Tags: c#, class, properties, required, modifier

I have two classes - State - Principal Class and District Dependant class.

```
public class State
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public required string StateName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }


    public static void CreateNewState()
    {

        State state = new State(); 

    }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework Core.

I want to create a 'New State'.

I get the errors below.

Required member state.StateName must be set in the object initiailzer or attribute constructor.

I am looking for guidance to use the required modifier correctly.  I am not able to understand how to use the object initializer or attribute constructor.

I have tried to understand how to use the required modifier in the properties of a class.  I am unable to understand the concepts.

Comment: Shingo, thank you for your response.  I was trying to over the nullreference error when trying to create a 'New State'.   https://code-maze.com/csharp-nullreferenceexception/.   One suggestion I found was to make the property required.  This is why I attempted to use the required property modifier.  I did go over the article you have indicated.  I was unable to understand the concepts.  Hence seeking help.

Comment: I am new to C#, hence I am asking very "Dumb" questions.

Comment: What state name do you want in the `State` created by `CreateNewState`? It's a required property, so you have to provide it - you're not doing so.

Comment: Thank you Jon and Shingo.  I am correcting my code now after learning a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I used the knowledge and directions given by Shingo and Jon and found the answer.  Thank you everyone!

```
public static void CreateState()
 {

     State state = new State() { StateName = "Karnataka" };

     RMIDbContext db = new RMIDbContext();

     db.States.Add(state);
     db.SaveChanges();

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**